# Does using cache_result essentially do the same thing as writing a temp table

Tags: snowpark

**Update 2022-08-31**

While the chosen answer did confirm that the behavior was similar, there actually is a blind spot which is that using the `cache_result` implementation will not overwrite the previous table which means that extra storage will be used up when re-caching a new result. In the example below, we can see that a new temp table is being created. Hopefully snowflake can update this. I'm using 0.8.0 at the moment.

```
>>> dff = session.create_dataframe([1,2,3])

>>> dff.cache_result().explain()

---------DATAFRAME EXECUTION PLAN----------
Query List:
1.
SELECT  *  FROM (SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_X3FCJ1U38A)
...

--------------------------------------------

>>> dff.cache_result().explain()

---------DATAFRAME EXECUTION PLAN----------
Query List:
1.
SELECT  *  FROM (SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_Z9H68STVDH)
....
```

---

**Original question**

In snowpark ml, does the `cache_result()` method for the snowpark DataFrame class essentially do the same thing as writing to a temporary table? It sure seems that way, and it would save a lot of keystrokes, but I just wanted to be certain of it as well as understand any potential difference in resource credit usage.

In other words, are there any differences to these two approaches below?

```py
sql = '''
select * from foo
'''

# Approach 1: saving to temporary table and then assigning the table
session.sql('...').write.mode('overwrite').save_as_table('my_tbl', table_type='temporary')
df = session.table('my_tbl')

# Approach 2: using Cache result
df = session.sql(sql).cache_result()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Die caching in Snowpark has an other meaning compared to Spark. `df.cached_result()` writes a temporary table. As the doc states:

https://docs.snowflake.com/ko/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/_autosummary/snowflake.snowpark.html#snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.cache_result

**Returns
A DataFrame object that holds the cached result in a temporary table.**

You can also verify by calling `df.cached_result().explain()` or the Python API source code

```
@df_collect_api_telemetry
def cache_result(
    self, *, statement_params: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None
) -> "DataFrame":
    """Caches the content of this DataFrame to create a new cached DataFrame.

    All subsequent operations on the returned cached DataFrame are performed on the cached data
    and have no effect on the original DataFrame.

    Examples::
        >>> create_result = session.sql("create temp table RESULT (NUM int)").collect()
        >>> insert_result = session.sql("insert into RESULT values(1),(2)").collect()

        >>> df = session.table("RESULT")
        >>> df.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2)]

        >>> # Run cache_result and then insert into the original table to see
        >>> # that the cached result is not affected
        >>> df1 = df.cache_result()
        >>> insert_again_result = session.sql("insert into RESULT values (3)").collect()
        >>> df1.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2)]
        >>> df.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2), Row(NUM=3)]

        >>> # You can run cache_result on a result that has already been cached
        >>> df2 = df1.cache_result()
        >>> df2.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2)]

        >>> df3 = df.cache_result()
        >>> # Drop RESULT and see that the cached results still exist
        >>> drop_table_result = session.sql(f"drop table RESULT").collect()
        >>> df1.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2)]
        >>> df2.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2)]
        >>> df3.collect()
        [Row(NUM=1), Row(NUM=2), Row(NUM=3)]

    Args:
        statement_params: Dictionary of statement level parameters to be set while executing this action.

    Returns:
         A :class:`DataFrame` object that holds the cached result in a temporary table.
         All operations on this new DataFrame have no effect on the original.
    """
    temp_table_name = random_name_for_temp_object(TempObjectType.TABLE)
    create_temp_table = self._session._plan_builder.create_temp_table(
        temp_table_name, self._plan
    )
    self._session._conn.execute(
        create_temp_table,
        _statement_params=create_or_update_statement_params_with_query_tag(
            statement_params, self._session.query_tag, SKIP_LEVELS_TWO
        ),
    )
    new_plan = self._session.table(temp_table_name)._plan
    return DataFrame(session=self._session, plan=new_plan, is_cached=True)
```

and

```
   def create_temp_table(self, name: str, child: SnowflakePlan) -> SnowflakePlan:
        return self.build_from_multiple_queries(
            lambda x: self.create_table_and_insert(
                self.session, name, child.schema_query, x
            ),
            child,
            None,
            child.schema_query,
            is_ddl_on_temp_object=True,
        )
```

So I would say there is **no difference** between calling `df.cached_result()` and creating a temporary table on your own

Comment: Vry clever pointing that out with explain. That said, I did find one fault with using `cache_result` which is that it doesn't overwrite the temporary table. I'll explain more in my comments.